# Adding remote git repository when it requires custom headers

Tags: git, http

I have cloned a git repo from one source, and trying to copy it (with it's history) to another git repository. I have to use http. If I were to clone the new repo the request would have to look like:

```
git -c http.extraHeader="custom: $VALUE" -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Bearer $PAT_TOKEN" clone https://<my-new-empty-repo>
```

But when I go to add this using `git remote add remote-repo https://<my-new-empty-repo>` and then push it using `git push remote-repo main`, obviously it fails as the headers arn't supplied. Is there a way of passing or configuring the headers so that pushing the remote-repo works?

Thank you!

Comment: You must supply this configuration (the configuration that is provided by the `-c` settings) on each network operation. That can be from the command line, as you're doing with `git -c ...`, i.e., `git -c ... push ...`, or you can put the `-c` settings into any Git configuration file. Just remember that the contents of such a file are generally available to anyone who can read the file, so tokens that last a long time are probably not a good idea for storage here.

Comment: Note, though, that anyone with any process running on your system can probably obtain any `-c` options you pass on the command line, so "I didn't put them in the file" doesn't mean "therefore I am secure from all threat actors". Secrets must be kept secret.

Comment: Thanks alot! `git -c ... push ...` worked.